# not able to implement chatting on android using socket.io and node.js

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

I am using Node.js and Socket.io on web server. and my client is on Android app. I am using Nkzawa libraries for chatting. But Unable to send or receive between two clients and even on server side.
Please help me.

code on client side.

```
try {
                socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.10:9090");
                socket.connect();  // initiate connection to socket server

            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

              send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        socket.emit("chat_message",chattext=chat_text.getText().toString());
                        adapter.add(new Data_Provider(position, chat_text.getText().toString()));
                        chattext=chat_text.getText().toString();
                        //position=!position;
                        chat_text.setText(""); 
                    }});



                socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                      @Override
                      public void call(Object... args) {

                          socket.emit("foo", "hi");
                          Log.d("1 socket connect", "successfuly really connected");

                      }

                    }).on("connection", new Emitter.Listener() {

                      @Override
                      public void call(Object... args) {
                      Log.d("socket connect", "successfuly connected to server");
                      }

                    }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                      @Override
                      public void call(Object... args) {
                          Log.d("socket disconnect", "successfuly disconnected");

                      }

                    });
                socket.on("chat_message", new Emitter.Listener() {

                        @Override
                        public void call(Object... arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                             String data = (String)arg0[0];

                                adapter.add(new Data_Provider(true, data));
                                chattext=data;

                        }
                    }).on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                          @Override
                          public void call(Object... args) {
                            Exception err = (Exception)args[0];
                            Log.d("err", ""+err);
                          }
                });;
```

Comment: please post the logs from logcat

Comment: D/friend id(1433): ---238916
 I/connected(1433): to http://192.168.1.10:7474/db/data/cypher
I/sent query as(1433): {"query":"START n=node(238916) RETURN id(n),n.First_Name,n.Last_Name", "params":{}}
I/Choreographer(1433): Skipped 171 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/1 socket connect(1433): successfuly really connected
D/friend id in chat individual(1433): {
 "columns" : [ "id(n)", "n.First_Name", "n.Last_Name" ],
D/friend id in chat individual(1433):   "data" : [ [ 238916, "Amit", "Joshi" ] ]
D/friend id in chat individual(1433): } 238916 Amit Joshi

Comment: You are not calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after inserting data. As a good practice, call add method in UI thread. In your example, it is called in non-ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just call socket.connect after all your socket.on methods.
like,

```
socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
socket.on("custo event",CustomHandler);_
socket.connect();
```